# Delete All Rows in SQL Table on Page Load

Tags: c#, sql, delete-row

I am loading data from an excel sheet into a SQL table and then joining that data to another table with a script. On Page Load of my program I would like to delete all rows from my "temp" table. I am currently doing this, but it is not working at all. By **not working** I mean nothing happens. No errors, but also it does not delete anything from my table. I set a breakpoint on the `if` and it doesnt even hit the break point.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn1;
            String strConnString1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString();
            sqlConn1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString1);

            string cleartQuery = "Truncate Table [My Table]";
            SqlCommand sqlCmdSelect = new SqlCommand(cleartQuery, sqlConn1);
            sqlCmdSelect.Connection.Open();
            sqlCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCmdSelect.Connection.Close();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens when you run it? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: Please describe what "not working at all" means in much greater detail. That can mean anything between and including compilation errors to unexpected behavior.

Comment: By not working, nothing happen. No errors, but also it does not delete anything from my table. I set a breakpoint on the "if" and it doesnt even hit the break point.

Comment: Could you show your connectionstring? Do you use the |DataDirectory| substitution string and AttachDbFileName?

Comment: You should drop and recreate your table is faster

Comment: When you set the breakpoint, does it stay a solid red circle, or does it become an outline?

Comment: It stays a solid red circle